# If I have a ILR how long can I stay away from the UK?

Tags: us-citizens

If I have a ILR how long can I stay away from the UK?
I have immigrated here and hold an ILR in my US Passport since 1987.
I have not paid to have a new ILR stamp in my passport as I felt the £900+ charge was outrageous and my MP has looked into it and as long as I carry my expired passports with me I can travel in and out of the Uk at will.
I am now looking to stay in Spain for an extended period of time and want to make sure I do not loose my ILR status.
How long can I say away?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is addressed in [Paragraph 18 of the Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/407944/Immigration_Rules_-_Part_1_20150302.pdf), which says in part...

> has not been away from the United Kingdom for more than 2 years; and

The workaround for this rule is given in Paragraph 19...

> A person who does not benefit from the preceding paragraph by reason
>   only of having been away from the United Kingdom too long may
>   nevertheless be admitted as a returning resident if, for example, he
>   has lived here for most of his life.

So your ILR will time out after 2 years of not residing in the UK.  If this happens, the remedy is a [Returning Resident Visa](https://www.gov.uk/returning-resident-visa)...

> You need a Returning Resident visa to come back to live in the UK if
>   you were previously settled (given ‘indefinite leave to enter or
>   remain’) and you have either:

...but these are notoriously [hard to qualify for](http://www.londonelegance.com/transpondia/faq-tip-%E2%80%9Creturning-resident%E2%80%9D-visa-rrv).